# Different codes from one mifare tag

Tags: rfid, mifare

I have two readers:

- mf7 (wiegand26)
- desktop usb reader (z2usb)

They send different codes from tags
(wiegand  -  USB):

13711284 - 6ECBD718

14056036 - CEA4D818

13409492 - 9E5BD718

---

How to convert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two operations: NOT and reverse bits :)

```
    public static Int32 CARD_CODE_LENGTH = 5;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length == 0) return;

        String value = args[0];

        if (value.Length < CARD_CODE_LENGTH)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        String cardCode = value.Substring(value.Length - CARD_CODE_LENGTH, CARD_CODE_LENGTH);
        String facilityCode = value.Substring(0, value.Length - cardCode.Length);

        Byte facility = ReverseWithLookupTable((Byte)(~Byte.Parse(facilityCode)));
        UInt16 card = (UInt16)(~UInt16.Parse(cardCode));
        Byte[] result = new Byte[2];

        var temp = BitConverter.GetBytes(card);
        for (var i = 0; i < temp.Length; result[i] = ReverseWithLookupTable(temp[i++]));

        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", facility.ToString("X2"), result[1].ToString("X2"), result[0].ToString("X2"));
        Console.Read();
    }
```